# Touch Screen equivalent (or best alternative) to a Type-Ahead Search Field

Tags: touch-screen, search-results

Type ahead fields are convenient in desktop applications, but what is the best alternative in a touch screen "kiosk" environment. We need to utilize the Windows OS keyboard and it becomes cumbersome when a user needs to move the keyboard to view the Type-Ahead drop down list.

What would be the best solution? Nix the type-ahead field all together or possible display those results in another location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today it is commonplace to just drop live search suggestions on websites for mobile. Take a look at two examples, both Yahoo! and Bing.

[image: Bing]

No suggestions.

[image: Yahoo!]

Yahoo! does the same.

In most cases, this makes the most sense, especially on phones, since your room is greatly diminished.

However, you could take a "think different" approach, and do something odd. Similar to what Firefox Mobile does.

[image: Firefox Mobile]

Here, you see Firefox puts up results in little bubbles, so you could take a similar idea and add them right above a search field, making it so keyboards do not affect it. In addition, Sylar has a point on Windows keyboards, so you should examine that. Basically though, I would ditch a list-view and do something a little more out of the box. Moving the results somewhere is probably your best choice, just make it easily accessible.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions and the screenshots, they have helped in thinking about "other" ways of displaying the type-ahead results!

Comment: @guarddoggraphics, Cool. I'm glad it helped!

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the on screen keyboard of the windows OS, itself has a type ahead field.

I typed "t" followed by "y" on my on screen keyboard and here is what I got,

[image: On screen Keyboard image]

As you can see, there is a full type ahead suggestions on the top layer.

Anyhow, if you are implementing your own, then  I would suggest you to use a similar design. Instead of having a drop down for text prediction/type ahead, you can use horizontal scroll bar to display options for text prediction/type ahead. (as in the keyboard example above or as you would typically see in your mobile).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately the onscreen type-ahead does not work too will with names or custom fields that are being read from a database. I like the idea of a horizontal scroll bar!